# Affectation Operator

Tags: php, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I want to make an assignment but it always shows me int (0) :

```
$multiple =  $multiple + ($V['V1'] * $V['V2']); ==> int(0)
```

This's my code :

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $k => $v) :

$multiple =  $multiple + ($V['V1'] * $V['V2']);

?>
<tfoot class="bg-warning">
     <tr style="border-top: 1px double grey; font-weight: bold">
         <td><? echo "TOTAL"; ?></td>
         <td><? echo number_format($multiple / $total * 100, 2); ?>%</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: where does `$V` come from?

Comment: Going to see the contents of `$V` plus the value of `$multiple` before the calculation is performed.

Comment: I tested my code I can return all values ​​of my query multiple except $multiple int ( 0)

Comment: PHP variable names are case sensitive. Do you really mean `$V` or `$v` ? Maybe if you showed much more code we'd figure it out.

Comment: Tec u're right. I used  different variables $V  and $v that's was the problem. Thanks

Comment: Uchiha, the problem with my variables Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $V['V1'] = 10;
    $V['V2'] = 20;

    @$multiple =  $multiple + ($V['V1'] * $V['V2']);

?>
```

Comment: Initialize values for variable , it will give you result.